# VSCode PHP intellisense data cached?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Sometimes when I change code in my PHP project, the change isn't detected by Intellisense. So, if I for instance change the argument count of a function. The referring code to that function does not go into error, when I change the refering code argument count it gives a code error. So Intellisense thinks the previous argument count should be used. I restarted VSCode, but that doesn't make a difference.

Seems like Intellisense caches it's data, and it isn't updated very well.

Example:

```
$instance= new SomeClass();
$result = $instance->some_function($variable1, $variable2);

class SomeClass {
public function some_function($variable1, $variable2)
{
   ...
}
```

Then I change it to:

```
$instance= new SomeClass();
$result = $instance->some_function($variable1);

class SomeClass {
public function some_function($variable1)
{
   ...
}
```

After save of both files, Intellisense gives me error:

```
{
   ...
   "message": "Expected 2 arguments. Found 1.",
   "source": "intelephense",
   ...
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Yes, as you said intellisense needs to build and index of your code.

Comment: You should maybe ask Ben about it. https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues

Comment: My question is, how can I rebuild the index of Intellisense?

Comment: I created a issue in Github as well. https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/693

Comment: F1 -> intelephense reindex workspace as shown on the screenshot https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/191

Answer (score 3):

Appears no longer an issue. With extension `Intelephense` enabled + with a `PHP` file opened in the editor, you can able to run the command `Intelephense: index workspace` which will rebuild the index.